# Форматирование текста в ASP.net Button

Tags: asp.net

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы можно было форматировать текст `asp.net` кнопок примерно так, а не вручную проставлять и дополнять строку пробелами.

> `1  Текст     Ещетекст
> 21 Текст45   Ещетекст`

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, так?

```
<button><pre>1  текст   Еще текст
21 текст   Еще текст</pre></button>
```